# Powershell - how to remove system accounts from Get-ChildItem searches

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I run the following script to get a basic audit of file permissions:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory E:\*,E:\*\*,E:\*\*\* |
Get-acl|
format-list @{N="Path";E={convert-path $_.Path}},AccessToString
```

In the results, I get the system accounts as well as the created ones:

```
Path           : E:\Path\To\Files
AccessToString : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                 <Domain>\<Group1> Allow  FullControl
                 <Domain>\<Group2>  Allow  FullControl
```

How can I strip out the `BUILTIN` and `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` from the results? Once the data is stored in a text file I can parse it out in Excel, but if I can get PS to remove them first it would make reporting more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, don't run things through the output formatters (`Format-...`) and expect to be able to usefully do anything with them afterwards, they're really for the last step of displaying information on the screen - and are prone to truncating fields, wrapping them, and generally not good for feeding into other programs either.

Excel reads CSVs reasonably well, so I've changed this to split the ACLs up, filter the BUILTIN and NT AUTHORITY lines first, then output each path once per ACL:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory E:\*,E:\*\*,E:\*\*\* | Get-Acl | ForEach-Object { 

    $path = Convert-Path $_.Path;

    $AccessStrings = ($_.AccessToString -split "`n") | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'BUILTIN|NT AUTHORITY' }

    $AccessStrings | Select-Object @{Name='Path';Expression={$Path}},
                                   @{Name='AccessToString';Expression={$_}}

} | Export-Csv -Path out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output format should be something like:

```
Path,AccessToString
"e:\file1.txt","DOMAIN\group1 fullcontrol"
"e:\file1.txt","DOMAIN\group2 fullcontrol"
```

so the paths will show up multiple times, because that seems like it fits Excel-shape better to me.

`'BUILTIN|NT AUTHORITY'` is a regular expression text match using `|` to match either/or.

Comment: That was perfect, thank you! I guess I had to stop piping out all of the output and actually write out genuine code to get this to work as needed.